# Using Cloud Scheduler to Call a Cloud Run Container

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a GCP project with a pipeline that scrapes a website at regular intervals. Right now, I have a Cloud Scheduler that calls a Cloud Function, which then calls a Cloud Run container that actually contains the scraping code. Recently, I was running into issues with authenticating the Run container, and posted about this. One of the responses I got was to remove the Cloud Function in the middle, as Cloud Schedulers can directly call Run containers. I was trying to figure out how to do this.

Currently, I use this code to call the Cloud Function:

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1
client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

job = {
        "name": f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/"
                f"locations/{LOCATION}/jobs/{cloud_job_name}",
        "description": "",
        "schedule": cron_str,
        "time_zone": "America/New_York",
        "pubsub_target": {
            "topic_name": "projects/{}/topics/{}".format(PROJECT_ID,
                                                        TOPIC),
            "data": schedule_message
        },
    }

    client.create_job(
            request={
                'parent': parent,
                'job': job
            }
    )
```

The only relevant variables here are TOPIC, which is a string containing the name of the Cloud Function I want to call, and schedule_message, which has a dictionary containing important information I need to pass to the Cloud Run container. I realized that all the Cloud Function does is take in this dictionary, and post it on the Run container, so if I could just use the Scheduler to call the Run container and give it the schedule_message dictionary directly, I wouldn't need the Function anymore. However, I don't think I can use a pubsub target to post to the Run container. I found a parameter called "http_target" but I'm not sure how to post the Run URL or the dictionary to it. How would the call to the Run container look like?

If any more information is needed, I'll post it. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: After familiarizing myself with the GUI, I looked up the Cloud Scheduler python API, and created a job to mirror what I did with the scheduler GUI. The code is as follows:

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1
client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

job = {
        "name": f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/"
                f"locations/{LOCATION}/jobs/{cloud_job_name}",
        "description": "",
        "schedule": cron_str,
        "time_zone": "America/New_York",
        "http_target": {
            "uri": "CLOUD_RUN_URL",
            "http_method": 1,
            "headers": {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
            "body": schedule_message,
            "oidc_token": {
                "service_account_email": "cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            }
        },
    }

    client.create_job(
            request={
                'parent': parent,
                'job': job
            }
    )
```

Note it's similar to the code I posted originally, but its modified to make a HTTP request to the Cloud Run directly.

The Cloud Run container allows all traffic, but requires authentication. I don't know how much code in the container I can actually post, because its private, but there is Main class with an on_post function that actually contains the code to run the scrape.

Comment: Cloud Scheduler can directly call Cloud Run. You do not need Pub/Sub in the middle. Review this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler The GUI can set up the call and authorization.

Comment: @JohnHanley This pipeline is connected to a website which can turn the scheduler on and off, so I was automating the process using code. I don't think I can use the GUI in this case. What should I do?

Comment: Automating what process? I recommended the GUI so that you learn how to configure things as a first step. Once you know what to do, you can then write code to do the same things.

Comment: @JohnHanley The website has the ability to create and delete schedulers using user input (one of which includes times and frequencies of scraping). Because of this, I can't manually create the schedulers using the GUI, and I'm using code to create the schedulers.

Comment: I am not sure how to help you. You are stuck insisting on writing code only when you do not understand how the services work or interoperate. Learn the fundamentals and then write code.

Comment: I apologize. The work is for a company, so I was trying to finish it quickly. However, your advice will probably be the best long-term investment. I'll use the GUI for now

Comment: Understood - time is valuable on the job. I am only recommending using the GUI to get your first test service setup. Then you know the steps and what to expect. Then write code to duplicate those steps and configuration. I think by using the GUI and then again using the CLI a **light** will go off in your head and then you will say **this is easy**.

Comment: @JohnHanley I need to pass a json dictionary from the cloud scheduler to the cloud run container (see "schedule_message" variable in the question). How is this done through the GUI? Do I just put the dictionary contents into the "body" input? Are there any headers that need to be included to accommodate these? I don't think this was covered in the example provided.

Comment: You do not need JSON to call Cloud Run.

Comment: @JohnHanley In my instance, the Cloud Run container needs some information to properly run its scraping task, so I need to pass down the JSON dictionary. Before, I just passed it from the Cloud Scheduler to the Cloud Function, and the Cloud Function used the "json" parameter in the requests.post python function to include the dictionary in the call to the Cloud Run container

Comment: @JohnHanley I just disregarded the json dictionary for now, and created a scheduler job with the GUI instructions you linked above to see if it would at least call the Run container. For some reason, the Cloud Run logs gave a warning with the content "*some_timestamp* POST 404 695 B *execution_time* Google-Cloud-Scheduler *Cloud_Run_URL*". There is no other error message. I assume it's not posting properly? Do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: Cloud Scheduler is most likely working fine. Either you have incorrectly specified the endpoint, Cloud Run is not set up correctly or your application is not handling the POST correctly. You have not updated your question to show the configuration for Cloud Scheduler or Cloud Run, nor the application running in Cloud Run.

Comment: @JohnHanley I added some more information. Does that shed light on what might be going on? As far as I know, I never modified the Cloud Run container from before; all I did was switch the scheduler to call the Run directly.